# Sending data from rails to Websocket server?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket, pusher

I have used web-sockets on the client side but I am confused on how to build and communicate with web-socket server.

My application is in rails,from what I understood I need a separate web-socket server(preferably node).

I know how the communication happens from client to web-socket server but want to understand how will the communication from rails to node websocket server will happen?

My use case is like this -> any database operation -> inform to websocket-server-> inform to client

I can approach via hosted api's like pusher.js but want to approach of my own

Would request your help, if you think I am not approaching the right way?

Comment: Your ruby app will essentially be a client to the websocket server. something like this : https://github.com/shokai/ruby-socket.io-client-simple

Comment: Thanks @BrahmaDev, for you help. Just to confirm is the way I am approaching is right or any better way?

Comment: "My application is in rails,from what I understood I need a separate web-socket server(preferably node)." - no, you don't... one option is to separate the servers, but you can use a single server / app for both (i.e., using [plezi.io](http://plezi.io) as middleware or using ActionCable).

Comment: I am not into ruby so I can't really comment on it or how well it deals with persistent connections. You'd have to research or benchmark it yourself.